# SYSLIB0021 Converting AesManaged() to Aes.Create()

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I'm upgrading the .NET version of our C# solution, and now it's giving me the SYSLIB0021 warning. I'd like to update the code rather than ignore the message. I have to retain original functionality though since there are stored files that I still need to be able to decrypt.

**Here's the original code:**

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Str);

var decryptor = new AesManaged();
var init = MyInit();
byte[] initB = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(init);
var rfc = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(init, initB);
decryptor.Key = rfc.GetBytes(16);
decryptor.IV = rfc.GetBytes(16);
decryptor.BlockSize = 128;

using (MemoryStream cryptoStream = new MemoryStream())
using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(cryptoStream, decryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
{
    cs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    cs.FlushFinalBlock();
    cryptoStream.Position = 0;
    using (MemoryStream compressedStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        cryptoStream.CopyTo(compressedStream);
        compressedStream.Flush();
        compressedStream.Position = 0;
        using (var zip = new DeflateStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            zip.CopyTo(stream);
            stream.Position = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

When I make the changes that Microsoft suggests on their site (as shown below), and then I try to decrypt one of the existing files, the data doesn't decrypt properly. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I can't simply call the Aes.Create("AesManaged") constructor because that too is obsolete.

**Here's my attempted refactor**

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Str);

var decryptor = Aes.Create();
var init = MyInit();
byte[] initB = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(init);
var rfc = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(init, initB, 1000, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1);
decryptor.Key = rfc.GetBytes(16);
decryptor.IV = rfc.GetBytes(16);
decryptor.BlockSize = 128;

using (MemoryStream cryptoStream = new MemoryStream())
using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(cryptoStream, decryptor.CreateDecryptor(decryptor.Key, decryptor.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
{
    cs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    cs.FlushFinalBlock();
    cryptoStream.Position = 0;
    using (MemoryStream compressedStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        cryptoStream.CopyTo(compressedStream);
        compressedStream.Flush();
        compressedStream.Position = 0;
        using (var zip = new DeflateStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            zip.CopyTo(stream);
            stream.Position = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can simply use `Aes.Create()`

Comment: ~~Looking at your snippet, my guess is that the change to use 4 arguments for `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` instead of 2 is the cause of the change.~~ I can see looking at the source you're passing through the same values the old constructors did, so it isn't that.

Comment: @Selvin when I try to use Aes.Create() as shown in my attempted refactor it doesn't decrypt the data properly.

Comment: @MartinCostello the 2 argument version of Rfc2898DeriveBytes() is also deprecated and Microsoft's documentation says that you should use the constructors that also specify the number of iterations and the algorithm type.
It should also be noted that in my refactor attempt, if I use Aes.Create("AesManaged") the decryption works fine. I just can't use that overload though because only the Aes.Create() with no arguments is not deprecated.

Comment: Setting the blocksize after loading the key and IV **may** also have something to do with it. 128 is the default anyway, so it is unnecessary. Anyway, you should get the same value for key and IV in both pieces of code, have you checked that?

Comment: You should post the encryption code or at least complete test data so that a repro is possible. Also you should describe for *all* codes which .NET versions they are executed with.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes had the correct solution. Removing the BlockSize assignment after setting the Key and IV fixed the issue. For some reason StackOverflow isn't showing the checkmark next to his answer, so I can't mark it as accepted.

Comment: That's because it is a comment, not an answer; I'll create one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Maarten Bodewes mentioned, I just needed to move the BlockSize assignment to happen before setting the Key and IV, or just remove it entirely since the default is 128 anyway.